# Como retornar cor em hexadecimal de forma randômica

Tags: css, sass

Estou querendo a cada build mudar o css da minha aplicação de forma randômica.

**Exemplo:**

```
$menu-color: #0097a7; // retonar apenas uma cor
$menu-color: random(#0097a7,#FAFAFA,#7FB800); // retorna uma color aleatoria.
```

Como o random retorna apenas um numero aleatório esta não seria a solução, como eu poderia resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira bem simples é usar `rgb()` em vez de `#hex`:

```
$red: random(256)-1;
$green: random(256)-1;
$blue: random(256)-1;
```

E em seguida:

```
color: rgb($red, $green, $blue);
```

Ou

```
background-color: rgba($red, $green, $blue);
```

Assim você além de ter a aleatoriedade, pode "calibrar" os tons gerados dosando o RGB (vermelho, verde, azul) com valores diferentes se desejar.

O curioso é que o SASS converte pra `#hex` e/ou cores predefinidas ao final. [Este blog](http://pankajparashar.com/posts/random-colors-sass/) dá algumas idéias de como contornar isso caso queira a saída usando `rgb()` literalmente.

Comment: Eu olhei esse artigo antes, mas achei um pouco complicado, exemplo: como apartir do hexadecimal: #FAFAFA eu vou obter o red,green e blue do rgb?

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a [resposta do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249843/102836) com a dúvida do seu comentário. Você pode obter novamente o **red**, **green** e **blue** da seguinte maneira:

```
$hex: #FAFEF0;

red($hex); // 250

green($hex); // 254

blue($hex); // 240
```

O exemplo completo:

```
$red: random(256) - 1;
$green: random(256) - 1;
$blue: random(256) - 1;

$hex: rgb($red, $green, $blue);

.color {
  color: $hex; /* Cor gerada randomicamente */
  background-color: rgba(red($hex), green($hex), blue($hex), .7);
}
```

Obteria algo semelhante á:

```
.color {
  color: #db7d39; /* Cor gerada randomicamente */
  background-color: rgba(219, 125, 57, 0.7);
}
```